# Rails order by attribute of last record from has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have two models with belongs_to and has_many relationship. BreedCycle has `breed_start_date` datetime attribute. What I am trying to do is to order `boxes` by newest(last created) breed cycle's `breed_start_date` attribute. Long story short, my goal is to write query that pulls out all newest breed_cycles for the boxes and order boxes by `breed_cycles.breed_start_date` attribute. Also `breed_start_date` can be nil so I need `NULLS LAST` option. Any help(link to docs, examples etc.) is greatly appreciated.

```
class Box < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :breed_cycles
end

class BreedCycle < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :box
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Box.left_joins(:breed_cycles)
   .group(:id) 
   .order('MAX(breed_cycles.breed_start_date) DESC NULLS LAST')
```

Or with [Arel in Rails 6.1+](https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/rails-6-1-adds-nulls-first-and-nulls-last-to-arel):

```
Box.left_joins(:breed_cycles)
   .group(:id)
   .order(BreedCycle.arel_table[:breed_start_date].maximum.desc.nulls_last)
```

Comment: Good answer. For PG I think a lateral is more performant but I like this for clarity/simplicity... but honestly I'd worry about either approach at scale / with if any other joins are necessary. If performance is a concern I'd consider cache'ing the date on the primary table so it can be indexed directly.

Comment: @melcher I would love to see what the lateral solution looks like. I still haven't quite wrapped my head around lateral joins.

Answer (score 1):

**Adding a [lateral-join](https://heap.io/blog/postgresqls-powerful-new-join-type-lateral) option as an extension to Max's answer.**

So - a lateral join is type of join supported by postgreSQL that's [like a correlated sub-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql), but more performant. I most commonly use it for situations like this one - where i have a "has many" but I only want to join a single one. Functionally they run just like how you'd expect a "for-loop" to operate - for each row in the table you're joining from, execute the lateral join and add in any rows returned.

Anyway, the lateral join SQL for this situation would look something like:

```
SELECT * from boxes 
LEFT JOIN LATERAL ( 
  SELECT breed_cycles.breed_start_date 
  FROM breed_cycles 
  ORDER BY breed_start_date DESC 
  LIMIT 1
) AS last_breed_cycle ON true
ORDER BY last_breed_cycle.breed_start_date DESC NULLS LAST
```

Turning that into activerecord would be something like:

```
lateral_join_sql = <<-SQL-
LEFT JOIN LATERAL ( 
  SELECT breed_cycles.breed_start_date 
  FROM breed_cycles 
  ORDER BY breed_start_date DESC 
  LIMIT 1
) AS last_breed_cycle ON true
-SQL
Box.joins(lateral_join_sql).order('last_breed_cycle.breed_start_date DESC')
```

I almost never use Arel so I'll leave that one as an exercise for the reader...

Answer (score 0):

try this. I don't have PG running to I can't test the `nulls last` piece, but I'm sure you can extrapolate...

```rb
Box.joins(:breed_cycles).
    select("boxes.*, max(breed_cycles.created_at) as most_recent_breed_cycle").
    group("breed_cycles.box_id").
    order("most_recent_breed_cycle")
```

does it give you what you need?

Comment: Hi, I have tried your query, pieces of it , and with some modifications, and I am not getting any results

Comment: Is your data good? What do you get for the query (in the rails console) `Box.first.breed_cycles.map(&:created_at)`?

Comment: [Tue, 24 Aug 2021 16:51:22.895868000 UTC +00:00,
Tue, 24 Aug 2021 16:51:22.904614000 UTC +00:00,
Tue, 24 Aug 2021 16:51:22.913040000 UTC +00:00,
Tue, 24 Aug 2021 16:51:22.920427000 UTC +00:00,
Tue, 24 Aug 2021 16:51:22.928809000 UTC +00:00]
this is what i get